# UMAP PicklingError: ("Can't pickle <class 'numpy.dtype[float32]'>: ...)

Tags: python, numpy, runumap

Trying to run UMAP causes an error:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import umap

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(25).reshape(-1,5))

um = umap.UMAP(random_state=0)
um.fit(df)
```

> PicklingError: ("Can't pickle <class 'numpy.dtype[float32]'>: it's not
> found as numpy.dtype[float32]", 'PicklingError while hashing array([[
> 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],\n       [ 5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.],\n       [10., 11., 12., 13., 14.],\n       [15., 16., 17., 18., 19.],\n
> [20., 21., 22., 23., 24.]], dtype=float32): PicklingError("Can't
> pickle <class 'numpy.dtype[float32]'>: it's not found as
> numpy.dtype[float32]")')

​
How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with Numpy.  I was running 1.20 when hitting this error.  Downgrading with

```
pip install numpy==1.19
```

resolves it.